# sort by minimum of two values

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I am building an app that gives you the option to sort a list of fuels available at different gas stations by cheapest, nearest location and cheapest nearby. However, I don't know what the correct code for the last one would be.
My code is looking like this right now:

```
switch searchMode {
        case .queryByNearby:
            orderedList.sort { $0.distance < $1.distance }
        case .queryByCheapest:
            orderedList.sort { $0.price < $1.price }
        case .queryByCheapestNearby:
            orderedList.sort { $0.price < $1.price && $0.distance < $1.distance }
}
```

is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You're going to need more logic than this. You'll have to make decisions about which gets precedence and by what amount. For example, what if A is $1 cheaper, but 10 miles further than B. Which gets sorted to the top?

Comment: @jnpdx I'd like it to be quite straightforward, like I want it to be sorted to the minimum of both values, so I thought it could be "easier". I can't think of a way to do it though

Comment: You can't mix distance and money in a meaningful way so _you_ need to decide what the logic should be for "cheapest nearby" and then explain that to us.

Comment: Imagine that the difference is A is at (2 m, 5$), and B is a (1m, 6$), diff. Which one would you prefers? Does 1m is the same as $1? See what the other mean?

Comment: You probably need to start by defining what is "nearby" is it 1Km? 5km?  Once you have that, filter your list to exclude the stations that are too far away and the sort by price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some of the comments have already mentioned, in 3rd case "cheapest nearby" you need to decide what has higher priority, price or distance. Based on that following solutions can be implemeted.

If price has higher priority

```
switch searchMode {
    case .queryByNearby:
        orderedList.sort { $0.distance < $1.distance }
    case .queryByCheapest:
        orderedList.sort { $0.price < $1.price }
    case .queryByCheapestNearby:
        orderedList.sort { $0.price == $1.price ? $0.distance < $1.distance : $0.price < $1.price }
}
```

If distance has higher priority

```
switch searchMode {
    case .queryByNearby:
        orderedList.sort { $0.distance < $1.distance }
    case .queryByCheapest:
        orderedList.sort { $0.price < $1.price }
    case .queryByCheapestNearby:
        orderedList.sort { $0.distance == $1.distance ? $0.price < $1.price : $0.distance < $1.distance }
}
```

You you could implement both and give 4 options to the user.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't know how to explain what I wanted to do nor how to do it, this was such good help